# Android: Every app closing after a while

Tags: android, memory, ram

I have an app which is closing after some period of time. The app is consuming around 20MB of RAM. I do have more than 120MB ram still available. I am not sure if this is the OS behavior or some problem with my app. Even with app like Opera mini, after a while it restarts again. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Problem with my app: I need to search the SD card for files with some specific extensions like mp3, jpg and some others and store it in local variables. When the app restarts again, it needs to do that work again. I need to avoid that. There are some app level settings which I am taking care using sharedPreferences. But the huge data is the problem.

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal behavior. Android will terminate processes after a period of time running in the background. Generally speaking, there is no "problem" for most well-written apps, that save user data to persistent storage (files, database, `SharedPreferences`) as activities get stopped, etc.

If you feel that you have a process that should live longer, please edit your question to provide a justification for this claim, as that may help us to provide recommendations on how to organize your app.

Comment: This doesn't happen too often with devices with more storage right? This has never happened to me. Guessing because all of my phones had a decent amount of ram.

Comment: @EGHDK: I guarantee you that Android has terminated processes on your devices, hundreds of times per day. Any time you press HOME and move some app to the background, it becomes eligible to be terminated.

Comment: @rahul: Use `MediaStore` rather than doing your own searching. Or, persist the results of your search to a file or database. "Local variables" are a cache, nothing more.

Comment: @EGHDK: It is true that apps  moved to background are eligible for termination if they occupy too much RAM. But I do not understand when the OS decides to do so. if the RAM is only 40% available or 30%.